# Не могу понять что не так делаю

Tags: c++

Не могу понять,какие ошибки у меня в коде что не хочет пробивать систему данные действия
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142870/discussion-on-question-by-gfkjdf-lkvfpodg-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 2):

Поможем машинистам. :)
Если не обязательно вводить переменные с клавиатуры, то их значения можно сразу указать в программе. Если обязательно - раскомментируйте блок с вводом.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
    double t,f,k,x,c,y,z,b; 
    t = 2; 
    k = 3;
    f = 4;
    x = 0.83;

/*    
    cout << "t="; 
    cin >> t; 
    cout << "f="; 
    cin >> f; 
    cout << "k="; 
    cin >> k; 
*/

    c = sqrt(t+1); 
    b = 0.7 * pow( c, 2) + f;
    z = 2.0 * pow( c, 3) + b;
    y = (0.2 * pow( z, x) + 0.5 * x) / pow( log( abs(c - pow( b, k)) ), 2); 

    cout<< "c=" << c << " y=" << y <<" z=" << z << " b=" << b << endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```